# Overlapping views and gestureRecognizer iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, z-index, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a question - is there any possibilities in iPhone to make UITapGestureRecognizer respond the tap only on a part of UIImageView. Actualy, the problem is as follows - there is an UIImageView with gesture recognizer add and some part of these UIImageView is covered with other View. When tapping on this other View, UIImageView recognizes the tap. How this problem can be solved?

Comment: if you get answer then tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want the gesture recognizer to be triggered when the view which overlaps the image view is tapped? If so, I guess you could just add the gesture recognizer to the overlapping view.

If you have two overlapping views and want to only handle the touch if the overlapped part was touched, I suggest adding the tap gesture recognizer to the main view and check if the overlap was touched.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecognizerTriggered:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)tapGestureRecognizerTriggered:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.frontView.frame, location) &&
        CGRectContainsPoint(self.backView.frame, location))
    {
        // Handle touch
    }
}
```

If you want to handle the touch if the touch happens in the front `CGRectContainsPoint(self.backView.frame, location)` from the conditional statement.

Comment: Sorry, my problem was the different one - I do not want my image to be triggered when view overlaps it

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need!